# How do I choose modules/libraries in Python?

Tags: python, package, python-module

(I'm a first-time poster and I think the guidelines don't exclude my question, but I added a more specific example just in case. I apologize if this turns out to be a subjective matter, I just assume there must be a proper standard way of doing this).

I'm a cognitive psychologists and currently supervising some students in a coding club. Since I never "properly" learned how to code, I tend to use the libraries I come across in the work of other researchers or the ones used in the tutorials. However, I realize this might not be the most efficient, straightforward or logic choice.

My question: What is the best practice in selecting a module and library? Is there a structured way to go about this?

A specific simple example: if I want to call a screen in an experiment, I know I can set it up with Pygaze, Psychopy or Pygame. I know each has their own pros and cons, but how do I know there isn't a more suitable one (or should I not care)? Is it better to pick a library that I can use for more components in the code (such as keyboard, timers, etc) or is it better to tailor this choice?

Comment: Just Googling would be the simplest option if you can't ask others what tools they use. "Python graphics library" or "Python timer library". Along with GitHub repositories, that'll also lead you to discussions on sites like Reddit that weigh the pros and cons.

Comment: Thanks @Carcigenicate, I never checked Reddit, that's a good tip. The problem I have is not having a decent overview and not very clear criteria to select with. Maybe I'm overthinking it, but I would just want to make a more informed choice. I'll dive in some discussion to get a cleared picture of how people review their choices.

Comment: Preferences are subjective, so finding existing discussions on the topic would be a good first step. I mentioned Reddit because they have many programming communities, and often have narrow discussions like that.